# ReadyBoost on Machines With Large Memory and Traditional HDD

Tags: windows, windows-7, readyboost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does ReadyBoost slow down systems with more RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/314156/does-readyboost-slow-down-systems-with-more-ram)

We have several Mac Pros (running Windows 7) with memory ranging from 8 to 16 GB, and 7200 or 10K HDDs. I'm considering install a 16GB flash drive for ReadyBoost on these machines.

I have no experience on whether ReadyBoost will be beneficial on machines with large amount of memory but (relatively) slow HDDs. Although all of these machines have few GBs of free memory, but Windows still use disk cache and I figure ReadyBoost might increase the disk cache performance.

Any thought is appreciated :)

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/314156/does-readyboost-slow-down-systems-with-more-ram

Comment: sounds like a dup to me. . .